# How to activate a react route and pass data from the service worker?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, single-page-application, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I have a SPA PWA React app.
It is installed and running in standalone mode on the mobile device (Android+Chrome).

Let's say the app lists people and then when you click on a person it diplays details using `/person` route.

Now, I'm sending push notifications from the server and receiving them in the service worker attached to the app. The notification is about a person and I want to open that person's details when the user clicks on the notification.

The question is:

- how do I activate the `/person` route on my app from the service worker
- and pass data (e.g. person id, or person object)
- without reloading the app

From what I understand, from the service worker `notificationclick` event handler I can:

- focus on the app (but how do I pass data and activate a route)
- open an url (but `/person` is not a physical route, and either way - I want avoid refreshing the page)

Comment: a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would help here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question: I've used IndexedDB (can't use localStorage as it is synchronous) to communicate between SW and PWA, though I'm not too happy about it.

This is roughly how my service worker code looks (I'm using idb library):

```
self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function(event) {
    const notif = event.notification;
    notif.close();
    if (notif.data) {
        let db;
        let p = idb.openDB('my-store', 1, {
            upgrade(db) {
                db.createObjectStore(OBJSTORENAME, {
                    keyPath: 'id'
                });
            }
        }).then(function(idb) {
            db = idb;
            return db.clear(OBJSTORENAME);
        }).then(function(rv) {            
            return db.put(OBJSTORENAME, notif.data);
        }).then(function(res) {
            clients.openWindow('/');
        }).catch(function(err) {
            console.log("Error spawning notif", err);
        });
        event.waitUntil(p);
    }
});
```

and then, in the root of my react app ie in my AppNavBar component I always check if there is something to show:

```
componentWillMount() {
    let self = this;
    let db;
    idb.openDB('my-store', 1)
    .then(function (idb) {
        db = idb;            
        return db.getAll(OBJSTORENAME);
    }).then(function (items) {            
        if (items && items.length) {
            axios.get(`/some-additional-info-optional/${items[0].id}`).then(res => {
                if (res.data && res.data.success) {
                    self.props.history.push({
                        pathname: '/details',
                        state: {
                            selectedObject: res.data.data[0]
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
            db.clear(OBJSTORENAME)
            .then()
            .catch(err => {
                console.log("error clearing ", OBJSTORENAME);
            });
        }
    }).catch(function (err) {
        console.log("Error", err);
    });
}
```

Have been toying with `clients.openWindow('/?id=123');` and `clients.openWindow('/#123');` but that was behaving strangely, sometimes the app would stall, so I reverted to the IndexedDB approach.
(clients.postMessage could also be the way to go though I'm not sure how to plug that into the react framework)

HTH someone else, and I'm still looking for a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can listen for `click` event for the Notification which you show to the user. And in the handler, you can open the URL for the corresponding person which comes from your server with push event.

```
notification.onclick = function(event) {
  event.preventDefault(); 

  // suppose you have an url property in the data
  if (event.notification.data.url) {

      self.clients.openWindow(event.notification.data.url);
  }
}
```

Check these links:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerGlobalScope/notificationclick_event
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clients/openWindow

Comment: I know, that is all stated in my question, but how to fit that with the react routing and avoid refreshing the SPA?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar need in my project. Using your's postMessage tip, I was able to get an event on my component every time a user clicks on service worker notification, and then route the user to the desired path.

service-worker.js

```
self.addEventListener("notificationclick", async event => {
    const notification = event.notification;

    notification.close();

    event.waitUntil(
        self.clients.matchAll({ type: "window" }).then(clientsArr => {
            if (clientsArr[0]) {
                clientsArr[0].focus();
                clientsArr[0].postMessage({
                    type: "NOTIFICATION_CLICK",
                    ticketId: notification.tag,
                });
            }
        })
    );
});
```

On your react component, add a new listener:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if ("serviceWorker" in navigator) {
        navigator.serviceWorker.addEventListener("message", message => {
            if (message.data.type === "NOTIFICATION_CLICK") {
                history.push(`/tickets/${message.data.ticketId}`);
            }
        });
    }
}, [history]);
```